# Retrieved values when listview item is clicked

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I created a listview using an adapter. the listview contains the distinct values of a particular field in a table. now,when the listview item is clicked, it should retrieve all items which have the id of that particular data. i manage to get the data from the listview but when the items are not fetched properly.

**row.xml**

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtid"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sd"
    />
```

**Tab2.java**

```
 ListView list;
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    HashMap<String, String> map2;
   final TextView a1;
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    a1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    final List<Product> sent = db.getSentProducts();
    for (Product s : sent) {
        map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("txtid", s.getMsg_id());
        mylist.add(map2);
        Log.d("msgid", s.getMsg_id());
    }
    for (Product s : sent) {
    }
    try {
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),mylist,R.layout.sent_row, new String[]{"txtid"}, new int[]{R.id.txtid});
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView a = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
            String content1 = a.getText().toString();
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            List<Product> sentinfo =  db.getSentProductInfo(content1);

           for (Product si : sentinfo){

                   Log.d("asdsd", si.getStorCode()+" "+si.getCode()+" "+si.getBstock()+" "+si.getDeliveries()+" "+si.getSpoilage()+" "+ si.getEstock()+" ");
          }

            return true;
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

**db**

[image]

**android ui**

[image]

When i click  20150824070159 in the listview, it should fetch two rows in the table, however, it only fetches one and it is the data of the other id, 20150820162104.

How will i be able to answer this?

Comment: The ListView positions start couting from 0, are you sure that you're getting the right value? Try to add other items to the list and see if it always get the value above the one you click or if it always return the first one.

Comment: I tried adding other values but the result is still the same. It always return the first one.

Answer (score 1):

To get the text from the item clicked on the list view you should do this:

```
 list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           String clickedText = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();                

        }
    });
```

Just make sure that your `list` variable is declared on the global scope, outside of any method, because this function will be called after the onCreate or any other method has already ended.